# Can an Angular app with version X use web components that have been bundled with ngx-build-plus in another Angular version?

Tags: angular, ngx-build-plus

I have an Angular app that is using version X of Angular and I want to use web components that are bundled with ngx-build-plus. However, the web components are using a different version of Angular when bundled than my app.

Is it possible to use the web components when they are built and bundled with an higher angular version than the app?